# How should the inevitable Canon vs Nikon (or Nikon vs Canon if you prefer) war be handled?

Tags: discussion, holy-war, subjective

As this is a group of photographers, there will almost certainly be the occasional conflict between Canon and Nikon users... How will these conflicts be handled?

Comment: Excellent question. I've already encountered a couple questions asking "which camera is best?". I've tried sticking the `subjective` tag on them, but it IS the inevitable *war*, sadly.

Comment: Can the title please be changed to "Nikon vs Canon (or Canon vs Nikon if you prefer)"?

Comment: +1 for the "holy-war" tag; that's something that should make it into the main site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It'll get downvoted into oblivion, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: In fact I believe this has already happened at least once.

Answer (score 8):

The stackoverflow approach is to just close such questions quickly. Works great.

Answer (score 2):

This, as Q&A site, isn't that much prone to endless arguments. If someone answers question about Nikon (or camera generic choice) with "Nikon sucks" they'd probably get downvoted/flagged quite quickly. The only issue are then questions like "Which brand is the best?", which can be contained (there aren't many unique variants of this question) and ignored by people who are not interested in brand wars.

Answer (score 1):

I think these sort of questions should be downvoted and deleted. Somewhere on the internet (can't remember where) I once read that dollar for dollar you will get about the same from Nikon or Canon so what beginners should ask themselves is "what do my friends and family use?" Since the lenses usually end up being the most expensive parts.

Comment: Or "What feels best to me" - The Canon cameras seemed to fit in my hands more easily than the Nikon equivalents, with better access to the controls.

Comment: That of course is a very huge factor, a camera can be a very personal thing so that is an even stronger point in not allowing religious wars.

Answer (score 0):

I think it definitely should be.

When starting into photography, this feels like an important question and one **people will ask**. Better they come here that some other forum where responses are just ranting noise.

I image the answer chosen will be along the lines of "There's not much difference, the quality of the photos is mainly down the the photographer" etc. etc.

As che mention, any responses like "Nikon sucks" will just get the chop.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that... hahaha